# What is Eclipse's structure?

Tags: eclipse

I appreciate the flexible structure of Eclipse.
I really want to know what programming language is used to write such software, and what design concepts are used in it to make it so flexible.

Comment: He's definitely going for gold here.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a community wiki ? We could talk all day about eclipse... which is a great IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is written in Java. The GUI toolkit is called SWT (Standard Widget Toolkit) which is also written in Java, but with small portions in languages like C to allow the native binding.

The architecture is highly plugin-based. With the exception of a minimal core, everything is a plugin. The plugin can provide [extension points](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_are_extensions_and_extension_points%3F) that other plugins can implement. With this mechanism, the mesh of plugins allows the high flexibility of the overall system. Wikipedia provides a [nice summary of the plugin architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Architecture).

The source of Eclipse is (to a large extend) very clean and provides lots of nice use s for the central design patterns, like Vistitors, Adapters, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

[Java was used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) to create Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

One way to visualize programming/markup languages used to write a piece of free or open source software is using Ohloh. [Ohloh's code analysis for Eclipse](https://www.ohloh.net/p/eclipse/analyses/latest) shows that many languages were used, but mostly Java, XML, and HTML.

Comment: XML is part of the Java ecosystem in a way - it's just a configuration format used by Java. My guess is that the HTML is just documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's open source - you can download it and examine to your heart's content.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the eclipse committers page [here](http://www.eclipse.org/committers/)

It's got all sorts of useful information, including answers to your specific questions

Answer (score 0):

When you look at http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/ you can actually read the source.  That should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Eclipse's plugin system for some interesting reading. A good start is its article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Architecture).